# Ruby Koans - Regex and .sub: Don't understand reason behind answer

Tags: ruby, regex

For clarification, here's the exact question in the `about_regular_expressions.rb` file that I'm having trouble with:

```
def test_sub_is_like_find_and_replace
    assert_equal __, "one two-three".sub(/(t\w*)/) { $1[0, 1] }
end
```

I know what the answer is to this, but I don't understand what's happening to get that answer. I'm pretty new to Ruby and to regex, and in particular I'm confused about the code between the braces and how that's coming into play.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The code inside the braces is a block that [`sub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-sub) uses to replace the match:

> In the block form [...] The value returned by the block will be substituted for the match on each call.

The block receives the match as an argument but the usual regex variables (`$1`, `$2`, ...) are also available.

In this specific case, the `$1` inside the block is `"two"` and the [array notation](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) extracts the first character of `$1` (which is `"t"` in this case). So, the block returns `"t"` and `sub` replaces the `"two"` in the original string with just `"t"`.

Comment: So, for clarification in my head, /(t\w*)/ is creating an array of ["two", "three"], then the rest of the code is matching the first item in the array ("two") and extracting the "t". Yes?

Comment: @Dave: `sub` only does one match (unlike `gsub` which catches all matches). The regex matches a "t" followed by zero or more (`*`) word characters (`\w`, alphanumeric plus "_") and the parentheses put the match in group one (`$1`). The result is that the regex finds "two" and that ends up in `$1` inside the block.

Comment: Thank you much. That definitely clarifies for me what's going on.